# Tengo problemas con tildes y ñ en android al consumir jsonParser

Tags: android, json, gson

Muestro el código en Json

> [{"Proyecto": "Daño -Causante Desconocido"}]

```
 class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        ///// getting JSON string from URL
        JSONArray json = jParser.makeHttpRequest2(url_all_products, "GET", params);
       // JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
        listaobjeto = json;




        /// //Log.i("jsonQR", String.valueOf(listaobjeto.length()));
        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < listaobjeto.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = listaobjeto.getJSONObject(i);
                //Log.i("jsonQR", );

                idR = Integer.valueOf(c.getString("IdRegistro"));
                rpt = Long.valueOf(c.getString("regptr"));
                des = c.getString("Proyecto");
                dir = c.getString("Direccion");


                CursoSQLHelper chelp = new CursoSQLHelper(MainActivity.this, "dataBD", null, 1);
                SQLiteDatabase db = chelp.getWritableDatabase();

                String sql = "INSERT INTO Produccion(IdRegistro,reg_ptr,descripcion,direccion,estado) values" +
                        "(" + idR + "," + rpt + ",'" + des + "','" + dir + "'," + 0 + ")";
                db.execSQL(sql);

                db.close();

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    /*} catch (Exception e) {
       throw e;
    }*/
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products;
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        pDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "La sincronizacion fue correcta ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

}
```

Me sale caracteres desconocidos  Da+-o-causante

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static JSONArray jObj2 = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if (method == "POST") {

                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                httppost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(params.get(0).getValue());

                httppost.setEntity(entity);

                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    if (response != null) {
                        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity
                        is=in;
                        //readStream(in);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex){}

            } else if (method == "GET") {
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }
            else if (method == "PUT") {

                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPut httppost = new HttpPut(url);
                httppost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(params.get(0).getValue());

                httppost.setEntity(entity);

                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    if (response != null) {
                        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity
                        is = in;
                        //readStream(in);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {            }
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }

    public JSONArray makeHttpRequest2(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if (method == "POST") {
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                /*
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                //httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

                httpPost.setHeader("Content-type","application/json");


                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                */

                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

                httppost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");


//Setting the Authorization header

                //String encoded = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((username+":"+password).getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.URL_SAFE|Base64.NO_WRAP);

                //httppost.setHeader("Authorization",encoded);


//String the data and set it as HTTP Parameters in the POST request

                //StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(getQueryJSON(nameValuePairs));
                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(params.get(0).getValue());

                httppost.setEntity(entity);

                try {

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    if (response != null) {

                        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity
                        is=in;
                        //readStream(in);

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex){}

            } else if (method == "GET") {
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                //httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                httpGet.setHeader("Content-type","application/json; charset=UTF-8");


                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                //String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8");
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj2 = new JSONArray(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj2;

    }
}
```

Comment: Prueba en la petición get a añadirle en el header el charset UTF-8: 
httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

Comment: voy modificar la pregunta mostrandote la el metodo jsonparser

Answer (score 5):

Ya estas realizando la petición para obtener datos codificados a UTF-8:

```
 httppost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

Entonces usa la códificación utf-8 para la respuesta, realiza el cambio dentro del método `makeHttpRequest()` :

```
  try {
     //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);    
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: is ?? de donde sale la varicble

Comment: @NaxinIA  inputstream, modifiqué la respuesta para que sepas especificamente donde realizar el cambio.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero usar este `JsonParser`Yo uso esta clase y no tengo problemas con los caracteres especiales. saludos

```
public class JSONParser {

String charset = "UTF-8";
HttpURLConnection conn;
DataOutputStream wr;
StringBuilder result;
URL urlObj;
JSONObject jObj = null;
StringBuilder sbParams;
String paramsString;

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  HashMap<String, String> params) {

    sbParams = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    for (String key : params.keySet()) {
        try {
            if (i != 0){
                sbParams.append("&");
            }
            sbParams.append(key).append("=")
                    .append(URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), charset));

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (method.equals("POST")) {
        // request method is POST
        try {
            urlObj = new URL(url);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

            conn.connect();

            paramsString = sbParams.toString();

            wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(paramsString);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if(method.equals("GET")){
        // request method is GET

        if (sbParams.length() != 0) {
            url += "?" + sbParams.toString();
        }

        try {
            urlObj = new URL(url);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(false);

            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    try {
        //Receive the response from the server
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        result = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

        Log.d("JSON Parser", "result: " + result.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    conn.disconnect();

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON Object
    return jObj;
}
```

}

Comment: ya me tare el json al momento convertir array jsonobject me sale error

Comment: tengo un array sin nombre es solamente [{...}] quiero convertirlo en jsonArray

Comment: lo cambio a tu codigo pero no me sirve para un array como lo ago

Comment: Quieres solo obtener los datos de una BD cierto o deseas insertar